# iOS payment apps: does Apple charge 30% of transacted amount?

Tags: ios-appstore

I'm in the process of developing a micropayment system, in which the consumers will use a mobile app to make payments.

Does Apple take their 30% cut from the revenue of a competing iOS payment app like this? The payment app in question is Bitcoin-based, so it does not make use of credit cards.

Can anyone point me towards the App Store terms of service pertaining to this?

Comment: I would recommend you contact Apple directly about this question instead of taking anyone else's word or interpretation on the rule.  If you're already in the Apple Developer Program you get 2 free consultations each year.  This appears important enough to your business to get Apple's official stance.

Comment: 1. Try searching before posting! 2. Read [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) and if you still are not sure, do as fsb suggested in his comment.

Comment: @fsb I have joined the Apple Developer Program in an attempt to clarify this issue. The only free consultation I can find is associated with WWDC17, which I do not plan on attending. Questions for the App Review team seem to be limited to rejections of an existing app. I'd rather prefer to know the answer to this question before writing any app code at all, since it's fairly important to the underlying business model. Am I missing something, or are there no other support channels to Apple besides these? To me, the forums don't seem appropriate for a question of this nature.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, Apple says

> **3.1.5 Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App:**
>
> If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry. Apps may facilitate transmission of approved virtual currencies (e.g. Bitcoin, DogeCoin) provided that they do so in compliance with all state and federal laws for the territories in which the app functions.